# Jquery Removeclass and Form Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have here a form validation. My textbox doesn't allow special character except (-) using Jquery validation. But the problems is the validation in bid and rfq textbox isn't working. It accepts special characters and submit the form.

This my working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mHCk7/1/

Help please?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

    var validation_holder = 0;
//  /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/


        var rfq         = $("form#register_form input[name='n_rfq']").val();
        var rfq_regex   = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
        var bid             = $("form#register_form input[name='n_bid']").val();
        var bid_regex   = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
        var mode                = $("form#register_form select[name='n_mode']").val();
        var mode_regex      =  /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/; // reg ex qty check

        /* validation start */  

if(bid == "" || bid.hasClass("mandatory")) {
        $("span.val_bid").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
        if(!bid_regex.test(bid)){ // if invalid phone
            $("span.val_bid").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;

        } else {
            $("span.val_bid").html("");
        }
    }

    if(rfq == "" || rfq.hasClass("mandatory")) {
        $("span.val_rfq").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
        if(!rfq_regex.test(rfq)){ // if invalid phone
            $("span.val_rfq").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;

        } else {
            $("span.val_rfq").html("");
        }
    }

        if(mode == "") {
            $("span.val_mode").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!mode_regex.test(mode)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_mode").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_mode").html("");
            }
        }           

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End



$('#txt1').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING' || $(this).val() == '') {
    $("#txt2,#txt3").val('');
    $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
    $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'BIDDING') {
    $("#txt3").val('');
    $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'RFQ') {
    $("#txt2").val('');
    $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else {
    //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
}
});
```

Comment: In case the fields have the class `mandatory` – which they do – you don’t _do_ the validation …

Comment: You need to use `&&` instead of `||`: `if (bid == "" && bid.hasClass("mandatory"))`. (Read: If the field is empty _and_ it is mandatory.)

Comment: Oh cmon, both of validation and removeclass is needed. What should I do?

Comment: @JohnS I tried it but it's not working. When the textbox is empty it's submits. -_-

Comment: Okay, but it does at least apply the validation when it is not empty. :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe the problem is it errors on the

```
if(bid == "" || bid.hasClass("mandatory")) {
```

any attempt to return false after this point is ignored... this is because bid is like the val not the html element!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your error raises here,

```
var bid = $("form#register_form input[name='n_bid']").val();
```

But you are checking the class with bid value like this,

```
bid.hasClass("mandatory")
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/mHCk7/3/) I modified your code.